# nhibernate join to table by foreign key not primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following two tables I'd like to join with fluent nhibernate:

ARTIKELATTRIBUTVALUES

- AAV_NKEY
- ART_PKNKEY
- AAV_SVALUE
- AT_NKEY

ATTRIBUTE

- AT_NKEY
- AT_SNAME
- AT_NTYPE

My Mapping for AttributeValue looks like this:

```
Table("ARTIKELATTRIBUTVALUES");
Id(x => x.Id, "AAV_NKEY").GeneratedBy.Custom<AutoIncrementer>();
Map(x => x.ArticleId, "ART_PKNKEY");
Map(x => x.AttributeId, "AT_NKEY");

Join("ATTRIBUT",
    jp => 
         {
           jp.Fetch.Join();
           jp.Map(x => x.Type, "AT_NTYP");
           jp.KeyColumn("AT_NKEY");
           jp.Inverse();
         }
     );
```

My problem is that nhibernate tries to join the two tables by the primary key: 
`( ATTRIBUTEVALUES.AAV_NKEY = ATTRIBUTE.AT_NKEY )`

How would I tell nHibernate to join by the foreign key: 
 `(ATTRIBUTEVALUES.AT_NKEY = ATTRIBUTE.AT_NKEY)`

Answer (score 0):

In theory you need to specify "property-ref" attribute, but this is not supported yet.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1452